# Scroll horizontal en Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, scroll

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]estoy tratando de hacer una lista de productos, pero quiero listarlos horizontalmente. El problema es que la lista supera los limites del container, no aparece el scroll para seguir viendo las imagenes.

Espero se entienda lo que digo.

Gracias

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="row d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap">

<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="thumbnail">
<a href="#">
<img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
<div class="caption">
<p>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural</p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="thumbnail">
<a href="#">
<img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
<div class="caption">
<p>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural</p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="thumbnail">
<a href="#">
<img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
<div class="caption">
<p>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural</p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="thumbnail">
<a href="#">
<img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
<div class="caption">
<p>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural</p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="thumbnail">
<a href="#">
<img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
<div class="caption">
<p>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural</p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me parece que esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38902310/8933039, podría solucionarle el problema.

Comment: Gracias @j-rodriguez